# How to Change layout from constraints to relative in android studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

hey guys im trying to change the layout file in android studio from constraint to relative because its part of my udacity beginners course to do this but the DIMEN thing is there

this is the code im trying to put in the activity main file
the parts ive put in square brackets are in red and are causing errors i dont know what to change them to. will someone help me with this?

Comment: Share your xml code

Answer (score 2):

delete the tag of Constraint Layout and write RelativeLayout in this place of this constraint layout tag in your XML code also close the tag with relative layout

Answer (score 0):

Hi You have to replace the contraint layout with relative layout. 
mydemo.xml with constraint layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <-- your code goes here --> 

 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Replace Above as below.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <-- write your code here-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

You are now done... Hope this help you.